# fswebcam: Unable to load font 'luxisr': libgd was not built with FreeType font support

Tags: linux, openwrt

I'm developing on an embedded device using OpenWRT. Whenever I try to use fswebcam to capture and image from my /dev/video0 and want to add some text to the image (--info switch), I get this error.

So the standard font 'luxisr' doesn't work. I've tried supplying my own .ttf font. Same result. Is there a font that fswebcam will be able to use without changing my current install, i.e. current libgd build? I'm thinking that including freetype font support in libgd, rebuilding and re-installing will be non-trivial (why wouldn't they enable it by default then).

Thanks for any help on this...

**UPDATE [march 31st, 2011]:** I've posed this question to Philip Heron, the author of fswebcam. This morning he let me know that:

> fswebcam right now can only use TTF fonts, and relies on freetype support in libgd to be able to render them. There's two options:

1. Rebuild libgd with freetype support. I'm not familiar with the OpenWRT build system but this might be the easiest option. Freetype seems to be packaged already so it shouldn't be *too* painful.
2. libgd also has a simple bitmap font built-in. I could have fswebcam fall back on this if no freetype support is detected, but it won't look nearly as good.

-Phil

So I'm going ahead and willbe re/cross-compiling libgd with freetype support.

Comment: apparently I'm doing something very unpopular. :(

Comment: Did you ever get it working, @Willem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is:

- Add libfreetype to .config
- Change `[buildroot_DIR]/package/feeds/packages/gd/Makefile`

and set line     `--without-freetype` to 
                 `--with-freetype=$(STAGING_DIR)/usr`

- (re-)build libgd and libfreetype packages and update OpenWrt system
- Then get a copy of the desired ttf (e.g. ubuntu /usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont/FreeSans.ttf)
- export GDFONTPATH
- set desired font in fswebcam.config

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. As far as I am concerned, fswebcam relies on the libgd library, which use the $GDFONTPATH environment variable to locate fonts. Within my environment (Ubuntu 11.04), such variable was not set.

Issuing an strace on the command line

```
$ strace fswebcam --font Arial:12 --save /tmp/test/test.jpg
```

Resulted in the following output

> access("/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/TrueType/Arial.ttf", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> ...
>
> access("/usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts/TTF/Arial.ttf", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
>
> ...

Which got me thinking that there were some problems with font look-up.

Setting a GDFONTPATH worked around the issue. For instance, I have used the following

```
$ export GDFONTPATH=~/.fonts/
```

Use (or any other font)

```
$ locate Arial.ttf
```

To get your font dir, which vary depending on your OS (/usr/local/share/fonts/truetype, /usr/share/fonts/truetype, ...) . Your millage may vary.

I'm sure something cleaner could be used but this solution works out. Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I found this question in google with the same error.
Just for info in debian:

`apt-get install ttf-xfree86-nonfree`

and add to fswebcam.conf:

`font /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-xfree86-nonfree/luxisr.ttf`

and run

`fswebcam --config /etc/fswebcam.conf`